# How to get taxonomy post link and display

Tags: php, permalinks, taxonomy

I had created this loop for getting the last added taxonomy category posts.Here is the code

```
 $issue = get_terms('articles-tax','orderby=Desc&order=ASC');
 $latest_edition = $issue[0]->slug;
 $latest_edition = $issue[0]->term_id;
 $postsart = get_posts(array(
 'showposts' => -1,
 'post_type' => 'articles',
 'tax_query' => array(
  array(
 'taxonomy' => 'articles-tax',
 'field' => 'term_id',
 'terms' => $latest_edition)
)) );        foreach ($postsart as $mypost) { ?>
 <div class="article_item"><div class="article_title"><?php echo $mypost->post_title?></div><div class="article_short_content"> <?php  echo $mypost->post_excerpt ?> </div>
        <div class="news_border"></div>
        <div class="news_readmore"><a href="<?php  ?>">Read More</a></div>
             </div>
```

So Now I cant get the permalink of the post, didnt know how to get from the array.Had done var_dump of $mypost, but cant manage how to get one item permalink.Help me to fix this pls!

Comment: `the_permalink()` not working for loop?

Comment: No it shows the page link that posts are in.

Comment: I had done var_dump but cant get the permalink from this array, what you think how we can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
 $permalink = get_permalink($mypost->ID);
 echo $permalink ;
```

It will give you posts' permalink

Comment: No it gave me page link

Comment: Yeah i have done just what you did and it works replaced $post to $mypost.Thx!

Comment: `get_permalink()` accept the ID of post , if it's giving you the page's link then I think you must use `wp_reset_query()` after the loop

Comment: I'd used it before but it wasnt working, but now works with $mypost->ID.

Answer (score 1):

Adding "global post" function to the code seems to do the trick

like this:

```
$postsart = get_posts(array(
 'showposts' => -1,
 'post_type' => 'articles',
 'tax_query' => array(
  array(
 'taxonomy' => 'articles-tax',
 'field' => 'term_id',
 'terms' => $latest_edition)
)) );   
global $post;
foreach ($postsart as $post) { 
setup_postdata($post);
?>
 <div class="article_item"><div class="article_title"><?php echo $post->post_title?></div><div class="article_short_content"> <?php  echo $post->post_excerpt ?> </div>
        <div class="news_border"></div>
        <div class="news_readmore"><a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink($post->ID);  ?>">Read More</a></div>
             </div>
```